# Installing plantuml plugin in Netbeans 8.1+

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

Is there an available plantuml plugin version compatible with Netbeans 8.1+. The one available (1.4/1.5) in the Netbeans plugin network is not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the version downloading the version for 8.0? http://plugins.netbeans.org/download/plugin/3376 It seemed to work for me even in 8.1.

Comment: Unfortunately no. After selecting it in the plugin manager, the list stays blank.